# How to avoid to link the unnecessary shared library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I've found something interesting during my C/C++ development under Linux. 
For instance, there are 2 shared libraries:

libfoo.so, which contains 1 function:

```
//------------libfoo.h-----------------
void func_foo();    

//------------libfoo.c-----------------
void func_foo() { return; }
```

libbar.so, which contains 2 functions. 
And one of them is dependent of libfoo.so:

```
//-------------libbar.h---------------
void func_bar1();
void func_bar2();

//-------------libbar.c---------------
#include "libfoo.h"

void func_bar1() { return; }
void func_bar2() { return func_foo(); }
```

But if a program only calls func_bar1(), which is independent of libfoo,  the gcc/ld still tries to search the symbol of func_bar2(), although the program doesn't need it at all. For instance:

```
//--------------------main.c------------
#include "libbar.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    func_bar1();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I've got the following error by linking:

```
gcc main.c -L . -lbar
./libbar.so: undefined reference to `func_foo'
```

So I have to do so to make it work:

```
gcc main.c -L . -lbar -lfoo
```

It seems like that the linker can't resolve the symbol func_bar1() in main.o, so it has to look for it in the following library list: libbar.so. And all the symbols in libbar.so should also be checked, no matter if the main program needs them or not.. But I'm not sure of my understanding.

Could anyone please tell me, how the link really works in this case. And is it possible to avoid to link to the 'unnecessary' libfoo ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you've got a shared library, it is an all-or-nothing proposition.  Either you've got everything, or you've got nothing.  If you only want some parts, either split the `libbar.so` library into two parts — one that depends on `libfoo.so` and one that does not — or use static libraries after all.  Then you'd be OK.

Answer (score 0):

When a `.so` file is mentioned in a `ld` command, it will be treated as an usual `.o` file. As we know, all symbols in a `.o` file (in this case it turns out the `libfoo.so`) must be resolved. That's why even in the `main` program you don't call `func_foo()`, that function is still needed to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, Kata.
And I've tested with this part of your answer:  

When main is loaded, bar will be also loaded; if one of bar's function is not found e.g. func_foo() main will crash although it does not use this function.   

It seems the main program will not crash:
First I built libbar.so without a dependency of libfoo.so: 
`void func_bar1() { return;  }       void func_bar2() { return;  }`
Then the main program works.   And I've changed the func_bar2() to `void func_bar2() { func_foo(); return; }` and rebuilt libbar.so. But the main was not rebuilt. Run the main again, and it didn't crash.

Comment: Well, in your two cases, every function is resolved OK so no crash :) Anw I updated my answer for more clear.